# Equivalence between geometric theories and frames internal to the free topos

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

What is a reference for ["the equivalence between geometric theories and frames internal to the free topos"](https://indico.math.cnrs.fr/event/747/contributions/2523/attachments/1818/1962/introductionJoyal.pdf)? [1] This seems to be an extremely interesting theorem.

[1] André Joyal, “A crash course in topos theory: the big picture”, lectures at Topos à l'IHÉS, 2015.

Comment: The videos for Joyal's lectures are in this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx5f8IelFRgFjhhrWWl96sRSClcG5YIx6 And the abstract for lecture 3 mentions the result the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simon essentially answered the question already, but I will expand some of the parts that may not be clear to the experts. Sketches of an elephant is a good reference for everything I am going to say.
I will take a bit of a different narrative to Simon's, implicitly assuming a good understanding of classifying topoi, blurring the distinction between a topos and the geometric theory it classifies, $$\mathcal{E} \simeq \text{Set}[\mathbb{T}] .$$

**Def (Prebounds).** Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos. A *prebound* $e \in \mathcal{E}$ is an object such that the subobjects of its finite powers $m: a \to e^n$ are a generator for the topos. Such an object always exist and can be obtained by manipulating a generator (or a site).

**Construction (From prebounds to localic geometric morphisms).**  Given a couple $(\mathcal{E},e)$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos and $e$ is a prebound, we can construct a localic geometric morphism $$f_e: \mathcal{E} \to \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]. $$
Of course, this is the same of a cocontinuous left exact functor $f_e^*: \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}] \to \mathcal{E}$, which is the same of a lex functor $\text{Fin}^\circ \to \mathcal{E}$,

$$\text{Topoi}(\mathcal{E},  \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]) \simeq \text{Cocontlex}( \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}], \mathcal{E}) \simeq \text{Cocontlex}( \text{Set}^{\text{Fin}}, \mathcal{E})\simeq \text{Lex}(\text{Fin}^\circ, \mathcal{E}). $$

The latter, is given by sending $n \mapsto e^n$. The geometric morphism obtained in this way is localic by definition of prebound. This construction appeared for the first time in **Freyd**'s *All topoi are localic*.

*Remark.* If you think about it, I am just spelling out in categorical terms what Simon suggested in somewhat mystical language.

*Remark (Morita-like phenomena)*. Notice that *each prebound* (and we can construct a prebound from any site) gives a different localic morphism, thus we have many localic representation for *the same* topos!

*Remark (Topoi are geometric theories, generators are their presentation)*. Following Thm 2.1.1 in **Caramello**'s *Theories, Sites, Toposes*, we see that a generator, or a site, is essentially the same of a linguistic presentation of the geometric theory classified by the topos.

**Theorem (Internal locales are localic geometric morphisms)**. There is a biequivalence of categories between the $2$-category of internal locales in $\text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]$ and the $2$-category of localic geometric morphisms over $\text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]$, $$\text{Loc}(\text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]) \leftrightarrows \text{Topoi}_{\text{loc} / \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]}. $$

*Proof.* Lemma 1.2 in **Johnstone**, *Factorization theorems for geometric morphisms*. Cahiers, 22, no1 (1981)

*Remark (On the emergence of Lawvere-like doctrines).* When one spells out what a locale internal to $ \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]$ is, one discovers that it is nothing but a functor $$\mathbb{P}: \text{Fin} \to \text{Frames}$$ verifying the Beck-Chevalley condition and Frobenius reciprocity (see Lemma C.1.6.9 and Cor. C.1.6.10 in Sketches of an Elephant). Suddenly we see how doctrine-like objects emerge in the representation of theories! That's beautiful in my opinion. $\text{Fin}$ acts as a fact as a set of variables, while $\mathbb{P}(n)$ gives us the poset (a frame in fact) of formulas on those $n$-variables.

**Def (Well presented topoi).** The $2$-category WTopoi of *well presented topoi* has objects $(\mathcal{E},e)$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos and $e$ is a prebound and morphism geometric morphisms whose left adjoint preserve the prebuound.

*Remark.* This notion does not appear in the literature (to my knowledge), I just need it as an intermediate notion. A good intuition for it is that the topos is specified together with a precise language generator of the geometric theory it classifies. WTopoi is really much more a $2$-category *of sites*, together with a *relational* notion of morphism of sites, rather than a $2$-category *of topoi*.

*Remark (Every topos can be well presented).* Of course, the WTopoi is not the same of Topoi but the forgetful functor $$\mathsf{U}: \text{WTopoi} \to \text{Topoi} $$ is essentially surjective on objects, and on morphisms (!).

**Theorem (Internal locales are well presented topoi and vice versa)**. There is a biequivalence of categories $$\text{Loc}(\text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]) \leftrightarrows \text{Topoi}_{\text{loc} / \text{Set}[\mathbb{O}]} \leftrightarrows \text{WTopoi}.$$

Comment: Why do internal frames give rise to functors into the category of Heyting algebras? (Specifically, why do the reindexing maps preserve the implication?)

Comment: By "topos", do you mean elementary or Grothendieck topos?

Comment: @ZhenLin, what I have in mind are Lemmas C.1.6.9 and Cor. C.1.6.10 in Sketches of an Elephant.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I was thinking about Grothendieck topoi the whole time.

Comment: So basically one needs to read papers of Freyd, Caramello, and Johnstone in addition to 1000 pages of the Elephant to understand the proof? Topos theory is really accessible. :-)

Comment: @user1022117 The gist of what I said, is the "Construction" in my answer. A lot of the answer also depends on what you intend by "geometric theory", that is if you a geometric theory is the data of its *presentation* or if it is essentially its classifying topos. In case your notion of geometric theory is a bunch of symbols and formulas, one can take a very neat shortcut.

Concerning the accessibility of TT, you must understand that you asked for "Can you prove Han Banach theorem" and you do not even accept that I need to define what is a Banach space (prebounds are a basic notion)?

Comment: Similarly, you are asking for a proof of Morely categoricity theorem in Model theory, but you want it to be completely elementary and not mentioning saturated models and Lachlan's theorem? I mean, it's not in-accessible, but "One does not simply walk into Mordor".

Comment: Firstly, I didn't ask about Hahn-Banach. Secondly, prebounds don't occur in the statement I asked about. Thirdly, you don't need to know about Banach spaces to state and prove the Hahn-Banach theorem. I really don't get your analogy.

Comment: I disagree, but feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: I won't downvote. Probably your answer is very helpful in 10 years when I have the right background to be able to read it. :-)

Comment: Is there any intuitive reason why geometric theories are frames internal to the free topos? How does one think about theories *internal to* a topos? Why is the object classifier called the free topos?

Comment: About the free topos, the best reference is Anel-Joyal "Topo-logie". It builts on an analogy with posets. I would not say that it is so telling for you. Concerning internal frames in a presheaf category, as I wrote, the correct intuition is that of hyperdoctrines. Fin are the variables, and P(n) is the frame of formulas in those variables.

Comment: @user1022117 I do not think at all that you are stupid, you are asking good questions, but you just lamented my storm of references, and this question in particular is not that connected to the main question you asked. I was trying to save you time!

Comment: @user1022117 The original reference would probably be "The Symmetric topos" by Bunge and Carboni. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks! But in which sense is the object classifier "free"? That question is pretty connected to my main question: the question uses the word "free topos", and an essential step towards the answer is to realize that this doesn't refer to the initial topos.

Comment: The forgetful functor Topoi $\to \text{Cat}^\text{op}$ is representable and has a left adjoint. Set$[\mathbb{O}]$ is the free object on $1$.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Thanks!

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I just want to say thanks again for all your help and sorry that I was a bit overwhelmed at first. I will come back to your answer again and again as I keep learning more topos theory!

Comment: @user1022117 I have a thick skin. If we happen to meet at a conference come and say hi to me, we'll laugh about this story in front of a beer.

Comment: @user1022117 I think one needs to be conscious that there is something else called "the free topos", namely the initial object in the (2-)category of elementary toposes and *logical* morphisms. Edit: ah, I see from another comment you know this already! As you were...

Answer (score 9):

When you think about it the right way the idea is fairly simple :

Here the "Free topos" means the "object classifier", that is the classifying topos of the theory with just one sort (one type) and no axioms. A Frame in this topos hence corresponds to a purely propositional geometric theory on top of this theory with one sort and no axiom, so you end-up with exactly a geometric theory with a single sort and as many propositions and geometric axioms as you want (so in particular, you can emulate function symbol using functional relations).

So frames in the free topos corresponds exactly to one-sorted geometric theory (with propositions and functions). In practice any geometric theory is (Morita) equivalent to a one-sorted one, so you can describe any theory like this. But the presentation as a frame in the free topos depends on what you chose as this sort.

I do not know a reference that present things exactly this way. But if you look in P.T.Johnstone Sketches of an elephant, you should find a good approximation to it as Theorem D3.2.5. The theorem might not be exactly what you are after, but it contains all the key elements. (Also using that localic geometric morphisms corresponds to internal frames of course)

Comment: Why is it appropriate to call the object classifier the "free topos"? (I know that usually that refers to Lambek's initial elementary topos.)

Comment: "A Frame in this topos hence corresponds to a purely propositional geometric theory on top of this theory with one sort and no axiom, so you end-up with exactly a geometric theory with a single sort and as many propositions and geometric axioms as you want" - Can you explain that? I don't understand the "hence". What you are claiming is exactly the theorem I ask about.

Comment: D3.2.5 states that on object B of a Grothendieck topos E is "pre-bound" (whatever that is) iff there is a single-sorted geometric theory T and an equivalence between E and Set[T] "which identifies B with the underlying object of the generic T-model". Firstly, I don't understand how this is related to the question I am asking. Secondly, what does "identifies B with the underlying ..." mean?

Comment: @user1022117 Read my answer.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I don't understand your answer.

Comment: What is you background in topos theory?! Because this is far from being a question at the level of "a topos is a lex reflection of a presheaf category".

Comment: It's sad that one can learn topos theory only if one studies at the right place where people teach it. Many things seem to folklore and scattered through many papers. Very inaccessible to outsiders.

Comment: I did not study at the right place for topos theory. It is true that it takes an enormous amount of time, though.

Comment: @user1022117 The part of th D3.2.5 you want is the equivalence between $T$ classifies a one sorted geometric theory (with generic model B) and the morphism $ T \to Set[O]$ corresponding to $B$ is localic. You then have to combined this with the fact that localic geometric morphism $ E \to T$ corresponds to internal frame in $T$. (Ivan gave a reference for this. I couldn't find a reference for this in the Elephant, except section C1.6 which deals with the case where $T$ is localic... )

Comment: @user1022117 : I didn't "learn at the right place" either. I learned topos theory on my own (from books) when I was a PhD student. If you want to learn start from one of the classical textbooks like MacLane and Moerdijk Sheaves in geometry and logic, or volume 3 of Borceux's handbook of categorical algebra. I also like McLarty's Elementary categories, Elementary topos if you want to learn directly through the lens of internal logic. The Elephant is a very valuable resource, but it was never meant to be a textbook : It is an encyclopedia.

Comment: @SimonHenry: Thanks for your answer, that helps!